# MvxCachingFragmentStatePagerAdapter pass parameter to viewmodel

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

How can i pass parameter to my viewmodel when i build a List of Fragment for a viewpager ?

I try to use the "parametervaluesobject" in "MvxCachingFragmentStatePagerAdapter.FragmentInfo"  but that doesn't seem to work.

```
[MvxFragment(typeof(MainViewModel), Resource.Id.content_frame, true)]
[Register("mvvmcrosslearning.droid.fragments.DateFragment")]
public class DateFragment : BaseFragment<DateViewModel>
{
    protected override int FragmentId => Resource.Layout.fragment_date;

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var view = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        var viewPager = view.FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.viewpager);
        if (viewPager != null)
        {
            var fragments = new List<MvxCachingFragmentStatePagerAdapter.FragmentInfo>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                fragments.Add(new MvxCachingFragmentStatePagerAdapter.FragmentInfo($"Date {i}",
                    typeof(RecyclerViewFragment), typeof(RecyclerViewModel), new Device() { Date = $"Date {i}" }));


            viewPager.Adapter = new MvxCachingFragmentStatePagerAdapter(Activity,ChildFragmentManager,fragments);
            viewPager.OffscreenPageLimit = 1;
        }

        var tabLayout = view.FindViewById<TabLayout>(Resource.Id.tabs);
        tabLayout.SetupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        return view;

    }
}
```

Comment: You could read this : https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/app-lifecycle#1-construction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks you York Shen. I found how to get the data in my ViewModel :
Just override that method in the RecyclerViewModel's ViewModel:

```
    protected override void InitFromBundle(IMvxBundle parameters)
    {
        base.InitFromBundle(parameters);
        Device = new Device()
        {
            Date = parameters.Data["Date"]
        };
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => Device);
    }
```